# Magento2: How to mass update the custom table status from ui component grid

Tags: magento2, custom, uicomponent, massaction

I have a ui component grid in admin which displays data from the custom table `multivendor_product` in which `id` is the primary key of the table and another field `product_id` is the product ID `catalog_product_entity.entity_id`. Here is the massaction tag in ui-component xml file,

```
        <massaction name="listing_massaction" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions">
        <action name="status">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">status</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Actions</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <argument name="actions" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">approve</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Approve</item>
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="mymarketplace/product/massStatus">
                        <param name="status">1</param>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="1" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">disapprove</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Disapprove</item>
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="mymarketplace/product/massStatus">
                        <param name="status">2</param>
                    </item>
                </item>

            </argument>
        </action>
    </massaction>
```

Now when I select the records and select one of the action, it is taking me to the controller `Custom/Marketplace/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/massStatus.php`, but I am not able to update the table.
What I would like is to update the table with the new status and also if the `disapprove` action is selected then disable the product also.

Could someone please help me with this. 
Thank you in advance